# Tried to install latest version of Web Platform Installer but now empty

Tags: php, windows, web-platform-installer

I am running Windows server 2012 and I wanted to upgrade to a later version of PHP.  My version of the Web Platform Installer was old and only showed up to PHP 5.2 and I wanted to install PHP 8.  So following this [process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3hBfrGmNKk), I downloaded and installed the latest version of Web Platform Installer, v 5.1.  However, now when I search for php, I see no results at all.  I don't understand why this is or how to recover.

[image: Search for PHP yields nothing]

Comment: Also, if I try and go back and install the old version that I had previously, it won't let me.  wow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx:

> The Microsoft Web Platform Installer (WebPI) was retired on December 31, 2022. For more information please see this blog post: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed

Comment: Lots of software gets retired but that typically doesn't mean it just stops working.  Also, it is working fine on other machines that I have.

Comment: How to install it on new machine and make it working?